Functional derivative and exterior derivative
Hello I hope this question is suitable for this platform. Are there specific rules to calculate $$\frac{\delta}{\delta A}(dA),$$ where $A$ is a gauge field on a three-manifold. Does it even make sense? If so, does the Hodge star $\ast_3$ and the variation commute such that $$\frac{\delta}{\delta A}(\ast_3dA)=\ast_3\frac{\delta}{\delta A}(dA).$$

The functional derivative is for functionals, and $dA$ is not a functional.

Functional derivatives commute past exterior derivatives as they act on different spaces, $ \delta d A = d \delta A$


If the 3-manifold does not have a boundary, then functional derivatives and exterior derivative commute, i.e.
$$\begin{align} \left[\frac{\delta}{\delta A(y)},\mathrm{d}^{(x)}\right]A(x)~=~&0, \cr 
\left[\frac{\delta}{\delta A(y)},\star_3\mathrm{d}^{(x)}\right]A(x)~=~&0, \cr 
\mathrm{d}^{(x)}~\equiv~&\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}
\end{align} $$

If the 3-manifold has a boundary, the existence of functional derivative depends on the choice of boundary conditions, which may jeopardize the commutativity of operations.


